# get sum of a object in array Javasript and store it

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object

i have this array :

here is a snippet :

```
[
  {
    "month": 9,
    "date": "2022-09-01T00:00:00",
    "week_nb": 35,
    "total_Value": 31.356,

  },
  {
    "month": 9,
    "date": "2022-09-17T00:00:00",
    "week_nb": 36,
    "total_Value": 67.726,

  },
  {
    "month": 9,
    "date": "2022-09-08T00:00:00",
    "week_nb": 35,
    "total_Value": 98.63,
  },
  {
    "month": 9,
    "date": "2022-09-24T00:00:00",
    "week_nb": 36,
    "total_Value": 55.178,
   
  },
....
```

i already specify this by month number

i want to get the sum of TOTALE_VALUE  of each  WEEK_NB

and store it inside a new array containt 2 objects like

`{week_number : X,  SumOfTotale_value : X },{week_number : X,  SumOfTotale_value : X }...`

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Most efficient method to groupby on an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446511/most-efficient-method-to-groupby-on-an-array-of-objects)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to sum the total value grouped by week.

We'd create an object with a property for each week number, then sum for each matching item.

[`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) can then be used to convert this object to an array as required.

```js
const input = [ { "month": 9, "date": "2022-09-01T00:00:00", "week_nb": 35, "total_Value": 31.356,  }, { "month": 9, "date": "2022-09-17T00:00:00", "week_nb": 36, "total_Value": 67.726,  }, { "month": 9, "date": "2022-09-08T00:00:00", "week_nb": 35, "total_Value": 98.63, }, { "month": 9, "date": "2022-09-24T00:00:00", "week_nb": 36, "total_Value": 55.178,  } ] 

const result = Object.values(input.reduce((acc, { week_nb, total_Value }) => { 
    acc[week_nb] = acc[week_nb] || { week_number: week_nb, SumOfTotale_value: 0 };
    acc[week_nb].SumOfTotale_value += total_Value;
    return acc;
}, {}));

console.log('Result:', result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

You can also use a [`for..of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop to get the same result:

```js
const input = [ { "month": 9, "date": "2022-09-01T00:00:00", "week_nb": 35, "total_Value": 31.356,  }, { "month": 9, "date": "2022-09-17T00:00:00", "week_nb": 36, "total_Value": 67.726,  }, { "month": 9, "date": "2022-09-08T00:00:00", "week_nb": 35, "total_Value": 98.63, }, { "month": 9, "date": "2022-09-24T00:00:00", "week_nb": 36, "total_Value": 55.178,  } ] 

const map = {};

for(let { week_nb, total_Value } of input) {
    map[week_nb] = map[week_nb] || { week_number: week_nb, SumOfTotale_value: 0 }
    map[week_nb].SumOfTotale_value += total_Value;
}

console.log('Result:', Object.values(map))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```